# How to get SceneKit SCNCameraController frameNodes to set target

Tags: ios, scenekit

The new SCNCameraController in iOS 11 looks very useful, but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any documentation other than the header file and a short description in the WWDC2017 video. The **frameNodes** function looks particularly handy, but it doesn't seem to actually work or at least not reliably. Specifically the header comment for frameNodes says:

*"Move the camera to a position where the bounding sphere of all nodes is fully visible. Also set the camera target has the center of the bounding sphere."*

For an array of nodes with more than one entry, it usually adjusts the camera so they are all visible, but it almost never seems to set the camera controller target to the bounding sphere of the nodes. At least I have not been able to get it to work reliably. Has anyone figured out how to get it to work (I'm using iOS 11.2.1 and Xcode 9.2)?

I've enclosed a playground to demo the problem. If I don't set the cameraController.target manually, the camera rotates around the torus, i.e., the target appears to be set to SCNVector(0,0,0). If I set the target manually then the camera seems to rotate around the correct target, roughly between the torus and the cube. If this is just a bug that I can work around, can anyone suggest a (straightforward?) way to compute the bounding volume for an array of nodes?

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView

sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
sceneView.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
sceneView.defaultCameraController.pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView

var torus = SCNTorus(ringRadius: 1, pipeRadius: 0.5)
var torusNode = SCNNode(geometry: torus)
torusNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(torusNode)
torus.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents  = UIColor.red
torus.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white

var cube = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
var cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cube)
cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(4, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
cube.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents  = UIColor.blue
cube.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white

SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.animationDuration = 1.0
sceneView.defaultCameraController.frameNodes([torusNode, cubeNode])
//sceneView.defaultCameraController.target = SCNVector3(2, 0, 0)
SCNTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Agreed, it isn't doing anything when I'm calling it. Definitely leaves the target unchanged.

Comment: Any solution to this? Did you figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

the bounding volume of an array of nodes could be shown by creating a sphere of radius equal to the largest x,y or z value (float) in the x,y,z arrays.

pseudo-code below:

```
maxval = 0
for i in x[] {
  if i > maxval {
     maxval = i
  }
}
for i in y[] {
  if i > maxval {
     maxval = i
  }
}
for i in z[] {
  if i > maxval {
     maxval = i
  }
}
let a = SCNSPhere(radius: maxval)
```